# Designating "nofollow" attribute on links in <div>

Tags: html, nofollow

I have the following code in a website footer:

```html
<div class="examples-footer">
    First text <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">Example</a> 
    Second text <a href="http://example.com/something" target="_blank">Example2</a>
</div>
```

I would like to designate the two links there as "nofollow". However, I can only manipulate the output by inserting additional text/html tags right after

```html
<div class="examples-footer">
```

and before

```html
First text <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">Example</a>
```

Just inserting the `<rel="nofollow">` tag there won't work; is there a way to do this using the HTML markup under the constraints which I specified, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want bots/crawlers/spiders to follow **any** links on the page, use the robots `meta` tag in the head:

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">
```

If you don't want search engines counting a link for page ranking, use the `rel` attribute in the link:

```
<a href="//stackoverflow.com" rel="nofollow">
```

Neither of these will prevent a human being (or cat) from following a clicked link, of course.